# AWS Cognito hosted-UI and preventing concurrent user sessions

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

Our website prevents concurrent user sessions. User can have their session active only on 1 device/browser at the same time. Today we are switching to AWS Cognito User Pools as authentication provider. Cognito hosted UI is used for sign-in. How to prevent concurrent user sessions on Cognito?

1. John Doe opens our website, clicks Sign-in
2. His browser navigates to cognito hosted UI https://save-ca-dev.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/user_sessions&response_type=code&client_id=4hlhf1cvm18lkst3dm8ru8oc73
3. John inputs his credentials, clicks Sign-in
4. He is redirected back to our website. He has signed-in successfully
5. John Doe opens our website on another PC.
6. Repeats Sign-in procedure. He has signed-in successfully on another PC.
7. On second Sign-in, **our website invalidates first user session** If he tries to work on first PC - he will be anonymous user.
8. Let's say John goes back to first PC and directly opens Cognito hosted UI [/login](https://save-ca-dev.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/login?redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/user_sessions&response_type=code&client_id=4hlhf1cvm18lkst3dm8ru8oc73)

**Problem**
Cognito still shows John as signed-in and will not ask his credentials
[image: sign-in-as-etruskas-gmail]

**Desired result**
Cognito should ask John's credentials. How I could achieve that?

I tried turning on Cognito Device tracking and remembering, it seems I could use ForgetDevice API. But all documentation leans towards mobile devices. Is that suitable for PC browser? Also, device tracking requires device credentials generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be possible to obtain the desired result using the Hosted UI, with its current design. 
To get the desired sign-out result, you would need to create a custom web/mobile application and utilize the [LOGOUT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) OAuth 2.0 Endpoint and the [GlobalSignOut](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GlobalSignOut.html) API accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to logout from cognito hosted UI also when your website invalidates the session.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html

Comment: In that case, user would be logged out from both PCs. Which is not desired behaviour.